# Forward button not working after history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pushstate

I've found how to fix the back button, but the forward button has remained unfix-able. The url will change but the page doesn't reload, this is what I'm using:

```js
$('.anchor .wrapper').css({
  'position': 'relative'
});

$('.slanted').css({
  'top': 0
});

// Do something after 1 second
$('.original-page').html('');
var href = '/mission.html'

console.log(href);
// $('#content-div').html('');

$('#content-div').load(href + ' #content-div');
$('html').scrollTop(0);
// loads content into a div with the ID content_div

// HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
history.pushState('', 'New URL: ' + href, href);
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  location.reload();
};

//            response.headers['Vary'] = 'Accept';
//            window.onpopstate = function (event) {
//                alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
//                            location.reload();
//                        response.headers['Vary'] = 'Accept';
//            };

//            $(window).bind('popstate', function () {

//            window.onpopstate = function (event) {
//                window.location.href = window.location.href;
//                location.reload();
//            };

e.preventDefault();
```

As you can see, I've tried several different things, and the back button works just fine but not the forward button.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Keep in mind that `history.pushState()` sets a new state as the newest history state. And `window.onpopstate` is called when navigating (backward/forward) between states that you have set.

So do not `pushState` when the `window.onpopstate` is called, as this will set the new state as the last state and then there is nothing to go forward to.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I didn't realize I was doing this until I read this answer. I had to separate the `history.pushState` call from the function so that I wasn't calling `history.pushState` when I used `window.onpopstate`.

Comment: Okay, This works perfectly. Saved a lot of my time.

Comment: old answer, still providing good information! I didn't realize calling pushstate from within the popstate event was overwriting my state. Makes sense now that I realize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Complete solution working with multiple clicks on back and forward navigation.

Register globally `window.onpopstate` event handler, as this gets reset on page reload (and then second and multiple navigation clicks don't work):

```js
window.onpopstate = function() {
    location.reload();
};
```

And, update function performing AJAX reload (and, for my use-case replacing query parameters):

```js
function update() {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    var startURL = currentURL.split("?")[0];

    var formParams = form.serialize();

    var newURL = startURL + "?" + formParams;
    var ajaxURL = startURL + "?ajax-update=1&" + formParams;

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: {id: $(this).attr('id')},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (dataRaw) {
            var data = $(dataRaw);

            // replace specific content(s) ....

            window.history.pushState({path:newURL},'',newURL);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading about navigating browser history and the `pushState()` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).  It explicitly notes that `pushState()` by itself will not cause the browser to load a page.

As far as the forward button not working, once you call `pushState()` the browser is (conceptually) at the last (latest) page of the history, so there is no further page to go "forward" to.

Comment: To clarify, I mean, after using the back button following pushState and then attempting to use the forward button does this.